# Quotient of free algebra - Noetherian/Artinian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian, artinian

Let $k$ be a field. Is the following ring noetherian/artinian?

$$k\left<x,y,z\right>/\left<y^2 - xyz^5\right>$$

I ran into this problem and have no idea how to deal with it. Please help!

Comment: To be clear, you mean these to be noncommutative polynomials?

Comment: Yes, I do. Thanks.